# Phaser 3 - Loading custom fonts from assets

Tags: phaser-framework, webfont-loader

I'm trying to figure out how to load fonts in to a phaser scene from local assets or google fonts.

In my game, I load all the assets in the first scene(Preload scene) and I don't want to load anything in my other scene's `preload` function.

**The problem is** I have multiple scenes in my game and fonts that are loaded in the first scene but not available in the other scenes.

I tried the `webfontloader` plugin and also the below example in phaser labs.

- https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/webfontloader/
- http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/game%20objects/text/static/custom%20webfont.js

How can I load fonts in my Preload Scene and use them in all the other scenes?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/38499-custom-font/ . Might you be starting your other scenes before the loading is complete.

Comment: @HarryScheuerle I think the `webfontloader` plugin handles that automatically. I'll try that manually also. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want pass the value from preload scene to other scene.

I recommend using object to save it.

This is how I pass the value to next scene.

```
let instance:globalParameter
class globalParameter {
    get gameData(): any {
        return this._gameData;
    }

    set gameData(value: any) {
        this._gameData = value;
    }
    private _gameData:any;

    constructor() {
    }
}

export default new globalParameter()
```

Comment: I think your answer is not relevant to the question. Its about loading fonts, not passing data from scene to scene.

Comment: You say : I don't want to load anything in my other scene's preload function.
So you want just load once in the first scene. I think the value can be stored on first scene and pass to other scene by object.